# Как перебрать массив и занести в переменную VBA

Tags: vba

Такая задача -

Есть массив `Dim arr(12) As String`

В каждом индексе содержатся слова. К примеру - `Полицейский`, `Пожарный`, `Врач` и тд. В пример возьмем эти слова.

Проблема заключается в том, что неизвестно в каком индексе будет, допустим, полицейский. Мне нужно найти в массиве слово полицейский и занести его в переменную `isPoliceMan`. И так с пожарным, врачом и тд. Соответственно, если какого-либо слова не было найдено, переменная будет `Empty`.

Как реализовать?

Comment: Сами подумайте, такую логику невозможно организовать. Как скрипт должен угадать что isGoodMan это какое-то значение?

Answer (score 0):

Как понял: не обязательно знать индекс. Нужно определить, есть ли значение в массиве и если есть, записать это значение в переменную.

```
Sub FillMass() 
Dim arr(0 To 11), j As Long
    For j = 0 To UBound(arr): arr(j) = j & "": Next j 
    Call FindInMass(arr)' заполненный массив передаем  обработчик'
End Sub

Sub FindInMass(arr())
Dim aStr()
Dim isPoliceMan  As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    aStr = Array("5", "2", "17") ' искомые значения'

    For i = 0 To UBound(aStr)
        For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
            If aStr(i) = arr(j) Then
                isPoliceMan = arr(j)
                ' здесь нужная обработка -'
                Debug.Print isPoliceMan  -'
                ' ------------------------'
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```